# Flutter Google Sign-In: Redirects to Home Page Or SignUp Instead of HomePage\SignUp Page for New Users

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on a Flutter app where users can sign in using their Google accounts. I've implemented Google Sign-In functionality, but I'm facing an issue with the navigation flow and Authentication.

When a new user signs in with Google, they should be directed to a sign-up page where they can provide additional information such as contact number, store name, and address. After providing this information, it should be stored in Firestore.
Now Next time when the user signs in With the same Google account he should be directed to the main page which btmnavbar in this case

However, I am unable to achieve this goal. The Code below does register a in Firestore with all the required details but next time when the user Signs In using the same Email it again navigates to SignUp page and asks to information
In the SIGN UP page the details should be stored against the same email which is selected in the login Page

LOGIN PAGE sinin Function

```
class _LoginAppState extends State<LoginApp> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool isHidden = true;
  bool isLoading = false;
  TextEditingController controllerEmail = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controllerPassword = TextEditingController();
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  TextEditingController resetPassController = TextEditingController();
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //////////Function for Google SIGN IN/////////////////////
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

  Future<User?> signingoogle() async {
    try {
      // GoogleSignIn().signOut();
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleaccount = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
      
      if (googleaccount == null) {
        return null;
      }
       print('Creating Google Auth');
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleaccount.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
        
      );
 
      final UserCredential userCredential =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
           
      final User? user = userCredential.user;
     
      if (user != null) {
        final CollectionReference users =
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
        final DocumentSnapshot emailDocument = await users.doc(user.uid).get();
        if (emailDocument.exists) {
          Navigator.push(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => btmNavBar()));
        } else {
          await users.doc(user.uid).set({'email': user.email});
          final AuthCredential emailAuthCredential =
              EmailAuthProvider.credential(
                  email: user.email.toString(), password: 'google password');
          await userCredential.user!.linkWithCredential(emailAuthCredential);
        }
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpGoogle()));
      }
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      print('$e');
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Here is My Sign Up Page Function

```
class _SignUpGoogleState extends State<SignUpGoogle> {
  TextEditingController contactController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController storeNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController addressController = TextEditingController();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  User? currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  Future<void> saveUserData(String userId, String email, String contact,
      String storeName, String address) async {
    try {
      // Save user data to Firestore
      await firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).set({
        'email': email,
        'contact': contact,
        'storeName': storeName,
        'address': address,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error saving user data: $e');
    }
  }
```

```
 SecondayBtn(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    var userContact = contactController.text.trim();
                    var storeName = storeNameController.text.trim();
                    var userAddress = addressController.text.trim();
                    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      try {
                        final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
                            await _googleSignIn.signIn();
                        if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
                          final GoogleSignInAuthentication
                              googleSignInAuthentication =
                              await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
                          final AuthCredential credential =
                              GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                            accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
                            idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
                          );
                          final UserCredential userCredential =
                              await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
                          final User? user = userCredential.user;

                          if (user != null) {
                            // Save additional user data to Firestore
                            await saveUserData(user.uid, user.email!,
                                userContact, storeName, userAddress);
                            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => btmNavBar()),
                            );
                          }
                        }
                      } catch (e) {}
                    }
                  },
                  btntxt: 'Sign Up With Google',
                ),
```

When a new user signs in with Google, they should be directed to a sign-up page where they can provide additional information such as contact number, store name, and address. After providing this information, it should be stored in Firestore.
Now Next time when the user signs in With the same Google account he should be directed to the main page which btmnavbar in this case

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue in the logic handling code determining where to navigate inside `signingoogle()` method. It always navigates to SignUpGoogle Page no matter what you are handling.

```
if (user != null) {
  final CollectionReference users =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  final DocumentSnapshot emailDocument = await users.doc(user.uid).get();
  if (emailDocument.exists) {
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => btmNavBar()));
  } else {
    await users.doc(user.uid).set({'email': user.email});
    final AuthCredential emailAuthCredential =
    EmailAuthProvider.credential(
        email: user.email.toString(), password: 'google password');
    await userCredential.user!.linkWithCredential(emailAuthCredential);
  }

  Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUpGoogle())); //<<< Here! This is outside of the if-else statement 
}
```